# Something wrong with my quick sort Python code?

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

I meet a issue with my quick sort code.

```
class Sort:
    def quickSort(self, unsortedlist):
        if len(unsortedlist) <= 1:
            return unsortedlist
        pivot = unsortedlist[0]
        unsortedlist.remove(unsortedlist[0])
        left, right = [], []
        for num in unsortedlist:
            if num < pivot:
                left.append(num)
            else:
                right.append(num)
        return self.quickSort(left) + [pivot] + self.quickSort(right)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [76, 76, 65, 72, 58, 64, 82, 3, 22, 31]
    print(Sort().quickSort(a))
    print(Sort().quickSort(a))
    print(Sort().quickSort(a))
```

The result will be:

```
[3, 22, 31, 58, 64, 65, 72, 76, 76, 82]
[3, 22, 31, 58, 64, 65, 72, 76, 82]
[3, 22, 31, 58, 64, 65, 72, 82]
```

Why the sorted list become less and less?

Comment: I suppose it removes the first element of the unsorted list because of `unsortedlist.remove(unsortedlist[0])`

Comment: @Guy No there is a recursion going on here... and the first element, pivot, is added back at the end.

Comment: You can solve the issue by calling `unsortedList =unsortedList[:]` in the beginning of your function

Comment: @Mathieu The element is never added back to the list. `.remove()` modifies the original.

Comment: Since your quickSort function returns a new list (as opposed to sorting the list in-place), you shouldn't modify the original list. Hence, do NOT use unsortedlist.remove(unsortedlist[0]).

Comment: @GuyIncognito Corrected, after the first iteration the initial list is only 8 elements long instead of 10.

Comment: There is also a discrepancy here: in most cases, you return a new list; but if the list has 1 or 0 elements, you return the old list. This will be very confusing for the user, who doesn't know if modifying the list returned by your quickSort function will modify the original list or not.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I've solved it by "make a copy" of the original list at the start of function, like `x = x[:]`. Avoid modify the old list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> unsortedlist.remove(unsortedlist[0])
> ```

So every time you call `quickSort` on a list you remove the first element *from the source* list.

It doesn't really matter for the recursive calls because you "control" the list, but for the "top-level" calls after every call to quickSort you've "lost" one of the elements.